# PyGame: How can I use a different part of my background image when my sprite goes past the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Like for example my game screen is 600 by 600, and my image is 600 by 1500. How can I make it so that my background moves to another part of the image when my sprite goes off screen, so it seems like I'm moving through but I'm really not?

Sorry if I seem confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean wrap the background?

Comment: Maybe....what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

From the pygame [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) on `blit`, you can pass in an area of your background image that you want to draw.

My pygame is a bit rusty, but you should be able to do the following:

```
blit(background_image, destination_surface, ((left_x_offset, 0), (right_x_offset, 0))
```

The first argument is your background image (the 600 x 1500 one), the second argument is the surface you're drawing everything to, and the third argument is the area of your background image that you want to draw to the  destination surface.

Since you want to move the background in relation to the character, I would set `left_x_offset` to the position of the character minus half the width of your screen, and `right_x_offset` to the position of the character plus half the screen size.

Comment: I tried doing it but it's not really working...maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @XVocalz If you update your question to include a sample of your code, perhaps you could get more help.